# How to get week number from date in this format YYYY-MON-DD in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a date in this format `YYYY-MON-DD`. Is there any way to get week number from the date which is in that format in `SQL Redshift`?

```
select clientId, window_time as day, count(*) as total_cont from data;
```

Here `day` column is in this format `YYYY-MON-DD`. How can I get week number from date in this format `YYYY-MON-DD`?

Comment: Apply `to_date` and `date_part` to the string representing a date.

Comment: Can you provide an example if possible? Sorry I am kinda confuse on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [DATE_PART function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html):

```sql
select date_part(w, listtime) as weeks, listtime
from listing where listid=10;

weeks |      listtime
------+---------------------
 25   | 2008-06-17 09:44:54
(1 row)
```

From [TO_DATE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html):

```sql
select to_date('02 Oct 2001', 'DD Mon YYYY');

to_date
------------
2001-10-02
(1 row)
```

Therefore, combine them together:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_PART(w, TO_DATE(dt, 'YYYY-Mon-DD')) as week
FROM data
```

Comment: what is `dt` here? it can be `window_time ` in my example right?

Comment: Sure. It's just a field in the table. I didn't want to use the reserved word `date` for the field name.